# Hardware accelerated android emulator with AMD GPU

Tags: linux-mint, android, amd-graphics, fglrx, emulators

I have come to the depressing realisation that the official driver for my video card: amd R9 208X is no longer supported for my OS: linux mint 18 (based on ubuntu 16.04LTS)

My main use for this system will (learning) to developing android applications, so running a smooth emulator is vital for me. Right now i am forced to use the obnoxiously slow software rendering, as Android studio / the AVD manager do not give me hardware acceleration with the default included Radeon drivers.

**my question: Do i have other options than to redo the install and go for a 14.04LTS based OS?**

I would hate to redo my system (again), and reverting to an older OS just feels plain sad...